# Is it possible to use DLR in a .NET 3.5 website project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm trying to evaluate an expression stored in a database i.e.

```
"if (Q1 ==2) {result = 3.1;} elseif (Q1 ==3){result=4.1;} else result = 5.9;"
```

Rather than parsing it myself I'm trying to use the DLR. I'm using version .92 from the Codeplex repository and my solution is a .NET 3.5 website; and I'm having conflicts between the System.Core and Microsoft.Scripting.ExtenstionAttribute .dll's.

```
Error =
{
  Description: "'ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'.", 
  File: "InternalXmlHelper.vb"
}
```

At this time I cannot upgrade to .NET 4.0 and make significant use of the .net 3.5 features (so downgrading is not an option).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to type forward ExtensionAttribte into System.Core.dll.  We've made 3 different versions of this assembly (for the 3 different versions that we've shipped w/ various IronPython versions) and attached to them on [this bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=19126) on IronPython's CodePlex site.

You'll need to download them and check the versions on them and replace the one that matches the version in the CodePlex release you're using.

Comment: Do I add the dll's to the GAC or to the assembly? Do I need one for Microsoft.Scripting.Core and Microsoft.Scripting? Is the source for the ExtensionAttribute with type forwarding available somewhere?

Comment: You replace it wherever you have the existing one.  If you put it in the GAC replace it there.  You just need the one - it'll fix both M.S.Core.dll and M.S.dll.

The source isn't that very interesting, it's just:

[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(ExtensionAttribute))]

And has a referene to System.Core.

Answer (score 0):

I might be to complex thinking right now and more easy solutions exists, but this jumped into my mind as a possibility;

Have you considered building a runtime class using the CodeDom, instanciating one, executing a method on it (with the expression as its implementation, which is more like code-snippets than a pure expression) and then retrieving the 'result' value from that class instance via a public property?